# Injecting WCF service proxy into viewmodel

Tags: wcf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, dependency-injection, prism-4

I currently have a Silverlight application using Prism and MEF. I connect to several WCF services in this application but use a "controller" class to hold the instantiated client-generated service proxy objects.

What I want to do is inject the service references into this controller (like I currently do with the IEventAggregator). I'm unsure how to do this. Do I need to make a wrapper class that implements the service contract interface, and holds a reference to the service proxy object?

What I do now:

```
/// <summary>
/// WCF client used to communitcate with the data WCF service
/// </summary>
private DataClient _dataClient;  // DataClient is the client generated object from a service reference

/// <summary>
/// Region manager for the application
/// </summary>
private IRegionManager _manager;

/// <summary>
/// Application event aggregator
/// </summary>
private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

/// <summary>
/// Constructor. Initializes the statistics controller, hooks up all services, and initializes all commands.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="manager"></param>
[ImportingConstructor]
public ZOpportunityController(IRegionManager manager, IEventAggregator events)
{
    _manager = manager;
    _eventAggregator = events;

    //hookup a WCF service used to retrive GP data
    _dataClient = new ZellerGpDataClient();  
    _dataClient.OpenCompleted += new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(_dataClient_openCompleted);
    _dataClient.GetCustomersCompleted += new EventHandler<GetCustomersCompletedEventArgs>(_dataClient_GetCustomersCompleted);
    _dataClient.OpenAsync();
}
```

As you can see here, I connect to a service in my controller constructor, but I'd like to just inject the service object into the controller like I do with IRegionManager and IEventAggregator.

**EDIT:** [This blog post](http://blogs.southworks.net/gmaliandi/2011/10/using-wcf-services-in-prism-silverlight-applications/) was really what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derive a client from [`ClientBase<TChannel>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and make it implement your service contract. The implementation of the contract look similar to this:

```cs
public class MyClient : ClientBase<IMyService>, IMyService
{
  void IMyService.DoSomething(Foo bar)
  {
    this.Channel.DoSomething(bar);
  }
}
```

Now you can just register that implementation with MEF or any other container and inject it via the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. "IMyService" would be the interface created by the service reference, correct? Also, since this is Silverlight (service calls are async) , using your example, would "MyClient" also be the one to hook up to async completed events? I'm thinking, if this is the case, I'll need to expose events to objects consuming the service injection?

Comment: @Ryan Sorry, I overlooked that you are using generated stuff. Then you should already have something like the above code. Add Service Reference generates something similar for you. If you use that generated code you will also get the events for free.

Comment: OK...so then, using the example from my code and your class name, would "MyClient" just hold a "DataClient" object in it? If so, how does the injection work...can I inject concrete classes? I was under the impression I had to inject interfaces.

Comment: @Ryan Unless MEF has some restrictions I don't know of you can import anything in your constructor (interfaces, concrete classes, primitives). Interfaces would allow you to swap one implementation for another without having to change your controller. But you can also inject a `DataClient` object.

Comment: Here is a good example of what I was trying to do. But your answer was the only one I received and it's still helpful. http://blogs.southworks.net/gmaliandi/2011/10/using-wcf-services-in-prism-silverlight-applications/